# Make parent control draw over child

Tags: windows, winapi, redraw

Is there a way to make the parent control draw over the children controls when it is invalidated?

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "draw over".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I know to affect this is to make sure the `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` window style is turned off. I haven't used this a lot though.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to completely draw over the child control, it may be easier to just hide the child control.